# Java re-assignment of an inherited field outside of a constructor

Tags: java

The title pretty much states my question. Why is this not possible? I am just wondering what the architectural reasoning might have been.

```
public class A{
    public int x = 5;
    public void m1() {System.out.println("Am1--> " + x);}
    public void m2() {System.out.println("Am2--> " + this.x);}
    public void update() {x = 99;}
  }
public class B extends A{
    x = 10;
    public void m2() {System.out.println("Bm2--> " + x);}
    public void m3() {System.out.println("Bm3--> " + super.x);}
    // public void m4() {System.out.println("Bm4--> " + super.m2());}
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code that demonstrates your question?

Comment: say having public int x = 10; in class A, and having x = 20; in subclass B. Initialization breaks down...

Comment: Please just edit your question with code that demonstrates it.

Answer (score 0):

inside **B** assign a value for **x** inside the constructor or any other method:

```
public class A{
    public int x = 5;
    public void m1() {System.out.println("Am1--> " + x);}
    public void m2() {System.out.println("Am2--> " + this.x);}
    public void update() {x = 99;}
  }
public class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super();
        x = 10;  
    }
    public void m2() {System.out.println("Bm2--> " + x);}
    public void m3() {System.out.println("Bm3--> " + super.x);}
    // public void m4() {System.out.println("Bm4--> " + super.m2());}
}
```